# ElasticSearch full text search using Java API

Tags: java, lucene, elasticsearch

I've recently started exploring the world of search, and am trying to use ES as the index for my MongoDB. I've managed to integrate them successfully, but I find the search API rather complex and confusing. The Java API is not too helpful either. I am able to find exact matches, but how do I do full-text searches? Here is my code:

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
    .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("host-ip", 9300));
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("mongoindex")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
    .setQuery(termQuery("name", "*name*"))
    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

I have no problems finding `"name":"testname"` using `.setQuery(termQuery("name", "testname"))`, but `"name":"this is a test name"` doesn't work with the above example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's just the database that i'm using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After crawling the Internet for hours, I've managed to figure it out, with some help from the [javadocs](http://es-java-doc.medcl.net). The most important is the interface `*QueryBuilder*`, and its implementing classes. I used `FieldQueryBuilder` for my query, which in shown in the `setQuery` method below.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("mongoindex")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
    .setQuery(fieldQuery("name", "test name"))
    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
for (SearchHit hit : results) {
  System.out.println(hit.getId());    //prints out the id of the document
  Map<String,Object> result = hit.getSource();   //the retrieved document
}
```

With the resulting Map object, you can simply call the `get` method to retrieve the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [termQuery in elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-query.html) uses Lucence for it's search syntax.  According to the [Lucene docs](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html) the "*" wildcard is not allowed as the first term of a search.

Comment: if that is the case, how could i search for a phrase (or substring) within text?

Comment: I would guess using a query_string http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not in Java, which is really the crux of my question, as I am using the Java API. I've seen the link but I can't translate it into Java.

Comment: Here's the source: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryStringQueryBuilder.java

Answer (score 0):

Better to look at [wildcard Query] (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)